# What is the meaning of the apearance of dogs in the good the bad the ugly?

Tags: analysis, the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly, sergio-leone

Last night I watched the 4K Remastered Edition of The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly. What a great movie!

Now I noticed something I'm curious about. There are several (at least 3, maybe 4) appearances of dogs in the movie. What does Leone want to say with the wild dogs? I think it's too easy to say the dogs stands for something like freedom or to try to illustrate the empty desert better. The pictures are the first and the last appearance of dogs in the movie.

Maybe the last dog is important to answer the question. It looks like the dog wants to run to Tuco but he scares the dog, so it runs out of the picture.

On youtube you can find the whole movie if you have to rewatch it ;-)

[image: First appearance]
[image: Last appearance]

Comment: Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar.

Comment: @MeatTrademark good answer, +1 ;)

Comment: Maybe you're right :-) Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: The three main characters are rather like stray dogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a nice scene just when the song Ecstasy of Gold starts. 
Actually the dog was not part of the original script. It was Leone's dog and it ran and escaped when the scene was shot. Elli's reaction is a natural instinct on being startled. Leone (perfectionist as he may be) liked the result so much that he decided to keep it

Comment: While this is an interesting information, do you have any evidence for this, or just an info where you got this from?

Comment: [IMDB.com](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060196/trivia) 2nd trivia

Comment: An intresting information?

Answer (score -1):

The dogs represent, believe it or not, the Holy Spirit connection of Tuco in this Divine story of how a border-line archetype learns and earns redemption... The movie is about the long journey Tuco has in learning to be a human.  Angel Eyes has lost redemption. Blondie has learned it, has learned: when you hit someone, remain human.  Tuco acts like this is not the assignment. Blondie insists it is.  The surprise ending allows Tuco to have the faith Blondie has in him… right now, Tuco cannot be trusted… but in time, he may learn… and later act more or less like the Jedi Master Blondie has become, and Tuco may someday teach a slow-learner, or stubborn one such as he, Tuco, is throughout the movie.  The song is all about Tuco learning, the movie is about the audience learning.